# Would the quad fly better with a 3S or 4S based on the weights of the batteries?

Tags: quadcopter

So the questions from the title is a bit hard to explain, so here is a better explanation of my question.

I want to get into the FPV quad flying hobby, so I decided to pick up a very starter quad, it's the Eachine Wizard X220. From the specs of the quad its lift off weight is 535 grams and the quad itself (without the battery but with all electronics) weights in at 364 grams. So I just need to pickup a battery everything else is accounted for. I want to get a 4S battery 1500 mAh which is 160 grams but that brings the total weight to 524.

So, my question is would the quad not be as efficient with this weight. Or should I just stick a 3S 1300 mAh and have a total weight of 484 grams?

Answer (score 1):

Adding more weight to a quadcopter will inevitably make the handling worse and reduce the flight time per Mah. However, we are talking about a 40-gram difference between these two batteries. It all depends on what matters the most to you when it comes to flight time and speed tradeoff.

A bigger battery is the better idea if you want the longest flight time possible. The trade off for more weight is less speed especially if the overall thrust of the engines is only 780g. [Aircraft specs from here](https://www.banggood.com/Eachine-Wizard-X220-FPV-Racer-Blheli_S-Naze32-6DOF-5_8G-48CH-200MW-700TVL-Camera-w-FlySky-I6-RTF-p-1077100.html). That being said, you would most likely only gain 1-3 minutes at the cost of speed.

I would suggest the smaller battery as its an FPV drone and more speed makes the whole experience more enjoyable. What I have learned over my many years of using quadcopters including both the DJI Mavik Pro and countless custom drones is that it doesn't necessarily matter if the battery on the drone is small. The thing that does matter is that you have spare batteries to swap out when the battery on the drone dies.

Answer (score 1):

3S makes more sense on lighter quads but a 4S may give you more flight time, if you're running a mid range weight quad.

I have raised this question on many occasions when building custom quads for friends.